# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/underscore-min.map")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, underscore.js, ruby-on-rails-5, gmaps4rails

I'm getting this annoying error everytime I refresh a page in my rails 5 app.
I need underscore.js for gmaps4rails. This underscore.js file is at vendor/javascript/underscore.js, like the tutorial says ([Gmaps4Rails Github repo](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)).

Does anyone have a good solution to solve or supress it?

Comment: you need `underscore-min.map` file

Comment: It suddenly stopped today. I wonder if it will come back.

Comment: I am also getting the same error.

Comment: Restart the server (computer). I got no better advice for solving this :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the .map file, or delete the line in your JS that calls it.

Comment: Where do you get the .map file?

Comment: You can find the .map file in underscore.js website, minified version:
http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 4):

to solve this issue, i do it:

1) copy code of underscore-min.map ([link is here](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore-min.map)) into a file which i renamed `underscore-min.map` and place it into assets pipeline (assets/javascripts)

2) in underscore-min.map, replace `underscore-min.js` by `underscore.js`

3) in `underscore.js`, uncomment last line (`sourceMappingURL=underscore-min.map`)

It work for me.
i hope it'll be help you too.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code in the question itself?

Comment: Yes, but my answer isn't helpful here? (I ask it because i'm novice on stack)